# how to define a background fill color when resizing and cropping with imagecache in drupal?

Tags: drupal, image-manipulation, gd, preset

Is there any way to apply some filters in imagecache to fill the background color with a html code preset #FFFFFF for example? , it's just impossible to set that up since scale & crop doesn't have no option for that...rotate however has it..
Can anyone help me please to set that up?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with [ImageCache Actions](http://drupal.org/project/imagecache_actions), which supports both GD and ImageMagick.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a job for an image manipulation program like ImageMagick.  You can use the [Imagemagick Raw Actions](http://drupal.org/project/im_raw) module to invoke this behaviour within ImageCache. I'm not an ImageMagick expert but you can specify a fill colour and use it with the [draw command](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/draw/#color).

Comment: I'm actually using GD, since Imagemagick is not installed and my server specifications doesn't allow that package to be installed,  so probably if there were some way to override the preset with php or something..